# How to exit the loop?

Tags: java

I have below code. I wrote a for loop and inside that I have switch statement. The switch has two cases and if `i==someOtherValue` is true then entire loop should exit.

```
for (//iterate over elements){
    int i = someValueTakenFromLoop;
    if(i==someOtherValue){

        switch(i){
            case 5:
                //some logic
                break;
            case 6:
                //some logic
                break;
         }
     }
 }
```

While iterating if `i==someOtherValue` is true then it should exit the loop. Do i need to keep break statement out side switch?.

```
    for(//iterate over elements){
        int i = someValueTakenFromLoop;
        if(i==someOtherValue){
            switch(i){
                case 5:
                    //some logic
                    break;
                case 6:
                    //some logic
                    break;
            }
            break;
         }
     }
```

Thanks!

Comment: _if i==someOtherValue is true then it should exit the loop_ && _if it i==someOtherValue is true then entire loop should exit._ doesn't make much sense

Comment: @JigarJoshi It seems a typo error while trying to format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,

When you break inside switch control just comes out of switch but not from the outside loop, so you will have to break outside switch again to break out of the loop, or else use labeled loop, but in case you use labelled code please make them capitalized for better readability, so that they stand out and can be read clearly, though Java convention suggests to use camel casing.

1

```
for(...) {
      switch(...) {
         break; // this will break from switch
      }
      if(condition) {
         break; // this will break from for loop
      }
   }
```

2

```
OUTERLOOP:
for(...){
   switch(...){
       break OUTERLOOP;       
   }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
mylabel:
for(...){
   switch(...){
      case x: break mylabel;
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm intrigued, is this an answer to the question? The OP wants to break out of the for loop if a condition is met.  Would this not start the for loop again if case x is hit? I'm not too good with Java so maybe I am missing something, could you clarify this?

Comment: @CarlWinder The break statement causes the for loop to stop iterating. What you describe is the functionality of another keyword named `continue` which would stop the current iteration and get back control to the for loop to continue with the next iteration.

Comment: ah right so it would break to mylabel and then carry on executing at the end of the for loop. am i right? I was thinking it was similar to goto mylabel; I assumed it mite have been a way of doing a goto in java.  Thanks for clearing that up :)

Comment: @CarlWinder You're right, the flow of control would continue with the next statement after the for loop.

Comment: Excellent thanks for that :) Next time I do anything in Java I'll be sure to remember this!

Answer (score 6):

If you have only 2 cases, why not using a simpler `if-else if` statement instead of `switch`?

Answer (score 0):

You should put a `break` as specified below:

```
if  (i == someOtherValue ) {  
  break; // breaks for loop
} // for some other value
// switch( to continue here
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Former `break` only makes it out of `switch` statement. The following one will work.

```
for(/*iterate over elements*/){
    int i = someValueTakenFromLoop;
    if(i==someOtherValue){
        switch(i){
        case 5:
            //some logic
            break;
        case 6:
            //some logic
            break;
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

edalorzo's solution is perfect, but I'd like to add one more thing (and don't have access to comments):

You can almost always restructure that kind of control structure using methods --

```
for ( /* ... */ ) {
    boolean finished = doSomething(i);
    if (finished) {
        break;
    }
}

//Later in the same class
private boolean doSomething(int val) {
    switch (val) {
        case 0:
            // do something;
            return true; // Break out of outer loop
        case 5:
            // do something absolutely terrifying
            break;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Edit:
Just noticed you meant to break independent of the switch condition - rather simple:

```
for ( /* ... */ ) {
    if ( /* ... */ ) {
        switch ( /* ... */ ) { /* ... */ }
        break;
    }
}
```